# Piece of modular code laravel where to put [Laravel, PHP]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3, modular

I have a tiny piece of code on my masterpage in laravel but it is a bit out of place, now I am wondering what is the best place to store this bit of code? It does need to run on every single page though.

```
<!-- user online-offline script -->
            <?php
                if(isset($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])) {
                    if(Auth::check()) {
                        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

                        $user->last_activity = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

                        $user->save();
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Should I store this in a seperate php file and use an @include on my masterpage for something like this or can I use a different approach with laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::filter('before', function() { });
```

should be a good place.

Comment: Wow, haven't even seen that yet in the routes file. Amazing, thank you alot.